# Coefficient restriction and cointegration

Tags: hypothesis-testing, cointegration, restrictions

We have [these data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j19ee67vzlzjcg9/data.csv?dl=0). $RL$ and $RS$ are six-month and three-month rates, and $S$ the spread ($RL-RS$).

Given that $RL$ and $RS$ are cointegrated, what is the best way to test $\beta_1=2$ in $\Delta{RS_t}=\beta_0+\beta_1S_{t-1}+u_t$? Dynamic OLS with HAC standard errors and then a Wald test? Apologies if I'm confusing anything.